# Default roles created by AWS Cognito Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

When I had created an AWS Cognito Identity Pool, two IAM roles have created automatically by Cognito: one for authenticated users and other to unauthenticated users.

The role for authenticated user has the following policies:

- Cognito Identity - Full access - All resources
- Cognito Sync - Full access - All resources
- Mobile Analytics - Full: Write - All resources

What do that policies allow effectivally ? Should I worry about with any security issues related to them?